# How do I store the result of a MYSQL procedure so I can use it in another procedure using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am having the hardest time of my life trying to figure out how to get this code to work. Basically, I have an html script getting values from a user, and I am taking those values and storing them in a database. I have procedures to do the storing, and those work... I am having a problem extracting values from a procedure for later use:

```
$addressID = "CALL get_addressID('".$_POST['street_address']."', '".$_POST['city']."', '".$_POST['state']."', '".$_POST['zip']."', '".$_POST['country']."')";
$creditID = "CALL get_creditID('".$_POST["name_on_card"]."', '".$_POST["card_num"]."','".$_POST["exp_date"]."','".$_POST["sec_code"]."', '".$_POST["billing_st_address"]."', '".$_POST["billing_city"]."', '".$_POST["billing_state"]."','".$_POST["billing_zip"]."','".$_POST["billing_country"]."')";
$obj = mysqli_query($conn, $creditID);
$SSS = mysqli_query($conn, $addressID); 
(line 100) $sql = "CALL add_customer('".$_POST["first_name"]."', '".$_POST["last_name"]."', '".$obj."', '".$SSS."', '".$_POST["email"]."')";
 if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
      echo "User data info stored successfully\n";
} else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

I would like to be able to use $obj and $SSS for this part so that I can create a user with them. I am getting the following error: "Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in C:\wamp64\www\project\CustomerAttempt.php on line 100"

The procedures i am running are as follows:

```
SELECT address_id FROM address where street_address = st_address and City = 
Fcity AND state = Fstate and postal_code = fzip and country = fcountry
```

and:

```
SELECT card_ID from credit_card WHERE Cardholders_Name = name_on_card AND Card_number = card_num AND Expiration_date = exp_date AND Security_code = sec_code AND Billing_Street_Address = billing_st_address AND Billing_City = billing_city_f AND Billing_State = billing_state_f AND Billing_Postal_Code = billing_zip AND Billing_Country = billing_country_f
```

I have no idea what to do, and am new to php, and mysql. Any help would be appreciated.

I am connected to my database with mysqli_connect using $conn as the variable for that.

Comment: The function query() returns an object on success. You have to retrieve the rows from that object. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your understanding of mysqli_query is just a bit off. This is what the php documentation states that mysqli_query will return.

"Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE."

In other words, your
    `$obj = mysqli_query($conn, $creditID);` line will return a mysql result object, not a string that you can append. In order to get the string for that, you can use
`$object = $obj->fetch_object();
$string = $object->columnName;`

columnName would have to be the name of the column that stores the value you are wanting to extract.

Comment: So as far as the column name goes, I'm now getting an error saying: Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$Card_ID in C:\wamp64\www\project\CustomerAttempt.php on line 106... Is it the name of the column on the database? or somewhere else? I verified that it is spelled exactly correct.

Comment: Well now the error is on line 106 and I'm not sure what line 106 is so it's a little tough for me to say exactly what the issue is. But to answer your question, yes it should be the column name in the database. For instance, if the whole point of that query was to get the value at "credit_ID", then that is what you would use.

Comment: Line 106 is: $string = $object->Card_ID;    which is the name of the column I'm using on my db

Comment: It's case sensitive. In your code above, it is card_ID, but the line you just posted is Card_ID.

Comment: No worries. Glad to help!